# How to create this kind of Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js to access this hdPrivateKey but it look like

```
 <hdPrivateKey...>
```

Not look like normal JS object.

And console.log(address) looks like

```
<Address: 19o9ghmkUrNVf4d57tQJuUBb2gT8sbzKyq, type: pubkeyhash, network: livenet>
```

`console.log(Object.keys(address))` look like

```
[ 'hashBuffer', 'network', 'type' ]
```

Why the key inside address are different?

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore');
var HDPrivateKey = bitcore.HDPrivateKey;

var hdPrivateKey = new HDPrivateKey();
console.log(hdPrivateKey)
var retrieved = new HDPrivateKey(hdPrivateKey);
var derived = hdPrivateKey.derive("m/0");
var derivedByNumber = hdPrivateKey.derive(1).derive(2, true);
var derivedByArgument = hdPrivateKey.derive("m/1/2");

var address = derived.privateKey.toAddress();
console.log(Object.keys(address))
console.log(address)
// obtain HDPublicKey
var hdPublicKey = hdPrivateKey.hdPublicKey;
```

Comment: I found this useful link https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8071.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is because the object has its own `inspect` property which is a function and returns a string. When `console.log` sees that it's logging an object, it looks for that function and uses it if available. So on Node, this logs `<foo>`:

```
const o = {
    inspect() {
        return "<foo>";
    }
};
console.log(o);
```

That's all that the `HDPrivateKey` object is doing.

If you want to properly inspect the object, use a debugger. Alternately, use [`utils.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) with `customInspect` set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, a `console.log` call the function `inspect` of the object. In the bitcore-lib there is this method :

```
HDPrivateKey.prototype.inspect = function() {
  return '<HDPrivateKey: ' + this.xprivkey + '>';
};
```

And this method:

```
Address.prototype.inspect = function() {
  return '<Address: ' + this.toString() + ', type: ' + this.type + ', network: ' + this.network + '>';
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.